# Reactive table shiny

Tags: shiny

I want to make a shiny app that show a table depends the parameters enter

```
  tabla4<- reactive({
    tabla<-activos_vabs[activos_vabs$Comunidades==input$com4 & activos_vabs$Sexo==input$sexo4 & activos_vabs$Edad==input$edad4, ];
   return(tabla);
 })
```

I have this and it doesn't show anything , but if i give the values, not with the input its works

```
  tabla4<- reactive({
    tabla<-activos_vabs[activos_vabs$Comunidades=="Total Nacional" & activos_vabs$Sexo=="Ambos sexos" & activos_vabs$Edad=="Total", ];
   return(tabla);
   return(prueba[5])
 })
```

I have a big table, and i just want to print a part .

Answer (score 0):

The below sample shiny code will solve your requirement.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(selectInput(inputId = "selectedName", label = "Select a name", 
                            choices = levels(data$name)),
                tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  df <- reactive({data.frame(data[data$name == input$selectedName,])
  })
  output$table <- renderTable( df() )
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

data used in code is below.

```
dput(data)
structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("aaa", "ddd", "eee", 
"ggg", "ppp", "yyy"), class = "factor"), test = c(14, 88, 36, 
25, 56, 34, 30, 75, 44, 19, 83, 49, 87, 62, 50), result = c(25, 
44, 39, 88, 10, 44, 58, 22, 94, 56, 73, 15, 84, 223, 45)), .Names = c("name", 
"test", "result"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Filtering of dataframe depends on the selection we make in `selectInput` dropdown.